# How to use drupal tokens using token_replace

Tags: tokens

Recently i developed a module which will prompt a message to user when he logs in 
Hi xyz .thanks for vising the site.
using drupal_set_message.Now in order for this to work i had to use 
token_replace($message,array(user=>$user)).
Now the object variable for user:name was $user . So just like this there are various other tokens available in drupal so how will i identify the object names of those variables and use them in token_replace to make sure that the message gets displayed with the proper values

Comment: Just an advise, ***Rules*** module is designed by experts to do exactly the sort of things you are trying to achieve. Give it a go.

Comment: how do i use it in my module to make sure that i get the logged in user name when he logs in..

Comment: You don't really need to use it in conjunction with your module, unless your module is processing some other business logic. You can install/enable Rules module on your Drupal and then setup a Rule to trigger an action when an event happens in the system (i.e. the event would be user has login, the action would be display a message), there are many tutorials out there and everything is configurable using GUI. If you wish to use Rules in your module then read up on Rules API integration.

Comment: Thnx raf ..but imagine its not simple message but some business processing itself string some business related data in DB and user name has to be recorded in that case i must use token_replace right?So how do i know the global variable names for each and every object and if i dnt,...can rule provide a one stop solution by integrating with my module